# How to unit test console output with mocha on nodejs?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, automated-tests, mocha.js, sinon

Take into account the following example Javascript code below:

```
function privateFunction (time) {
  if (time < 12) { console.log('Good morning'); }
  if (time >= 12 && time <19) { console.log('Good afternoon'); }
  else { console.log('Good night!'); }
};
```

How should I unit test that on nodejs using mocha (and possibly sinonjs), noticing that this is a private function called inside a module? I need to pass in the argument and check if the function is logging the right thing to the console.

Can I do the same with `console.warn` and `console.error`?

Answer (score 50):

I prefer [`mocha-sinon`](https://github.com/elliotf/mocha-sinon) over "plain" sinon because it integrates nicely with Mocha.

Example:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
require('mocha-sinon');

// Function to test, can also be in another file and as long as it's
// being called through some public interface it should be testable.
// If it's not in any way exposed/exported, testing will be problematic.
function privateFunction (time) {
  if (time < 12) { console.log('Good morning'); }
  if (time >= 12 && time <19) { console.log('Good afternoon'); }
  else { console.log('Good night!'); }
}

describe('privateFunction()', function() {

  beforeEach(function() {
    this.sinon.stub(console, 'log');
  });

  it('should log "Good morning" for hours < 12', function() {
    privateFunction(5);
    expect( console.log.calledOnce ).to.be.true;
    expect( console.log.calledWith('Good morning') ).to.be.true;
  });

  it('should log "Good afternoon" for hours >= 12 and < 19', function() {
    privateFunction(15);
    expect( console.log.calledOnce ).to.be.true;
    expect( console.log.calledWith('Good afternoon') ).to.be.true;
  });

  it('should log "Good night!" for hours >= 19', function() {
    privateFunction(20);
    expect( console.log.calledOnce ).to.be.true;
    expect( console.log.calledWith('Good night!') ).to.be.true;
  });

});
```

One potential issue: some Mocha reporters use `console.log` as well, so the tests that stub it may not yield any output.

There's a workaround, but it's not ideal either because it will intersperse Mocha output with the output from `privateFunction()`. If that's not a problem, replace `beforeEach()` with this:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  var log = console.log;
  this.sinon.stub(console, 'log', function() {
    return log.apply(log, arguments);
  });
});
```

Comment: If you use spy instead of stub then the workaround is not needed.

Comment: @TMG I'm actually starting to wonder if the workaround won't cause issues with calls to `console.log()` being made by reporters interfering with the call count of the stub/spy. Probably not, because I would think reporters only report _after_ the test has run. In any case, using a spy is indeed a better solution.

Answer (score 7):

ignoring the fact that it's a private function, i would take a couple of steps; refactor my code for better separation of concerns, and utilise this separation with test doubles.

- take all the side effects outside to their own modules (the side effect here is writing to the console):

  **out.js**

  ```
  function log (message) {
    console.log(message);
  };

  module.exports = {log};
  ```

  **app.js**

  ```
  const {log} = require('out');

  function greeter (time) {
    if (time < 12) {
      log('Good morning');
    }
    if (time >= 12 && time < 19) {
      log('Good afternoon');
    } else {
      log('Good night!');
    }
  };

  module.exports = {greeter};
  ```
- use some module proxy/spy, like [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) to replace the whole out writer when testing:

  **app.spec.js**

  ```
  describe('output writers', function(){

    const fakeOut = {
      log: sinon.spy(),
    };

    const app = proxyquire('./app', {
      'out': fakeOut
    });

    it('should log to the fake out', function(){
      app.greeter(15);
      assert(fakeOut.log.calledOnce);
    });
  });
  ```

Answer (score 5):

If your purpose is *solely* to test console output, I would suggest instead of stubs / spies etc on method calls, to use something like:

- [test-console](https://github.com/jamesshore/test-console)
- monitor stdout/stderr instead, you can use ideas from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/bsatrom/1349384/653dc18ac285bbae5399585d9bdfd3455214c1d5)